# ClassNotFoundException when using external jar

Tags: java, jdbc, intellij-idea

I'm using `IntelliJ Idea`. I've built my application and created it as a `.jar` file. This program uses an external `.jar` file for its database driver.

When I run the program from the IDE, it works fine. When I try to run my `.jar` file outside of the IDE, it reports the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException
        at ca.vdts.dbupdate.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

The directory of the `sqljdbc42.jar` file is in the manifest.
I'm on Windows, and I'd like to run this by clicking on the '.jar' file.
The application .jar file and the sqljdbc42.jar files are both in the same directory. On the command line, executing...

```
C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\DBUpdate\out\artifacts\DBUpdate>java -classpath .\sqljdbc42.jar;DBUpdate.jar -jar DBUpdate.jar
```

... results in the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException
        at ca.vdts.dbupdate.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: What command did you run on the command line? Where is `sqljdbc42.jar` located in the filesystem?

Comment: when you run your program in IDE, IDE adds this jar to the `classpath`, but when you you run this program by yourself you don't do that, so you get the error message. Add this driver jar file to the classpath, when you start your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running your application with:

```
java -classpath sqljdbc42.jar:Application.jar -jar Application.jar
```

Replace the `:` with a `;` under Windows.